# I can't get a variable of loop

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a simple batch file

The script gets namefile for the file "dump" and I split the string, but i can't display the variable !!

```
for /r %%a in (dump\*) do (
        set file=%%a
        for /f %%i in ("%%a") do (
        for /F "tokens=1 delims=-"  %%d IN ("%%~ni") do set db=%%d          
    )
 echo %db%
)
pause
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting the `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` and swapping the var with exclamation marks instead, see below:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /r %%a in (dump\*) do (
        set file=%%a
        for /f %%i in ("%%a") do (
        for /F "tokens=1 delims=-"  %%d IN ("%%~ni") do set db=%%d          
    )
 echo !db!
)
pause
```